# Buttery Chocolate chip cookies

Tags: baking, cookies, butter

How do I make chocolate chip cookies taste more buttery? I do use real butter (I have tried both salted and unsalted). Should I try a particular brand? European butter?

Comment: You might share your recipe (or a link to it if it is available online) so that we can know what your working from.

Answer (score 2):

The exhaustively researched [Serious Eats](https://sweets.seriouseats.com/2013/12/the-food-lab-the-best-chocolate-chip-cookies.html) article `The Science of the Best Chocolate Chip Cookies' has some relevant ideas.

In particular: browning the butter beforehand (as in a [buerre-noisette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beurre_noisette)) brings out its nutty flavours. Since this removes moisture, it might be necessary to compensate by adding a bit more egg or egg yolk. Melting the butter gives a denser cookie that should taste more buttery than the more `cakey' cookies from the creaming method.

European butter has slightly [more butter fat](https://www.thekitchn.com/whats-the-difference-between-european-and-american-butter-229135) than American butter (minimum 82% versus minimum 80%), giving a richer taste. I suggest experimenting with several different brands.